# Can a discrete variable turn into a continuous variable as its denominator approaches infinity.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, continuity

I am defining a set of points on the cartesian plane based on their coordinates, and I use the variables m and n. n is the number of points, and for all $m\in \left \{ 1,2,3,  ...    ,n \right \}$ the x and y coordinates of these points are given by algebraic expressions in the terms $\frac{m}{n}$, $\frac{m+1}{n}$ and $\frac{1}{n}$. So m iterates through all natural numbers until it reaches n. For example:
$$x-coordinate = \left ( \frac{n}{n+1} - \frac{m}{n+1} \right )\cdot \left ( \sin(\theta) -  \frac{m}{n}(\sin\theta + 1) + \frac{\sin(\theta)}{n} + \frac{m}{n} \right )  $$

I haven't derived the expression for the y coordinate yet, but it will be in terms of these variables as well. Essentially, the points mark out the rough shape of some curve, and as the number of dots approaches infinity, the points will exactly resemble this curve. While I could use algebraic manipulation to express y in terms of x using the two expressions for the x and y coordinates, I feel this would take too much effort. I realised another way and am posting this question to confirm whether or not it is actually possible. You see, the fraction $\frac{m}{n}$ ranges through all values $$\frac{m}{n}\in\left \{ \frac{1}{n},\frac{2}{n}, ... , \frac{n}{n} \right \} $$ For lack of a better word, I call this a discrete variable since it can only take discrete values(although discrete variable probably means something else). However as $n\rightarrow \infty$, wouldn't the fraction start becoming continuous? In other words, would I be right to say that as $n\rightarrow \infty$,  $\frac{m}{n}\rightarrow t$, where t is a parameter, or a "continuous variable"? I would then be able to replace $\frac{m}{n}$ with t in the expressions for the x and y coordinates, and end up with a parametric equation in t, which would give me the equation of the curve that I am looking for. And lastly, if this is true, then what does $\frac{m}{n+1}$ approach as $n\rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: What you're thinking of is called a continuum limit. It is a thing, but it isn't as conceptually simple as you're describing it.

Comment: By the way, $\sin(\theta) -  \frac{m}{n}(\sin\theta + 1) + \frac{\sin(\theta)}{n} + \frac{m}{n} = \left(1 - \frac{m-1}n\right) \sin\theta.$

Comment: @Ian I searched it up but wasn't able to find anything helpful. This website talks about it (https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2204/what-specifically-does-the-phrase-continuum-limit-mean) but the article does not mention anything about the exact maths behind it and its 'rules'. If you know about this I would really appreciate an explanation of this 'continuum limit' and how it may apply to my scenario. Thanks!

Comment: If $\frac mn \to t$ as $n \to \infty,$ then also $\frac m{n+1}\to t$ and $\frac{m + 1}n \to t.$ I'm curious, however, why you have $\frac mn$ in one place and $\frac m{n+1}$ in another. It might help if you showed the previous steps that got you to your formula for $x$ coordinates.

Comment: @David K the mathematics leading to the expression provided in the question is quite long, but I can tell you about the context behind it. Essentially what you do is connect the points (0,1) and (0.1 ,0) with a line, then do the same for (0, 0.9) and (0.2 , 0), and so on until you connect (0 , 0.1) and (1,0). You will observe that these lines create a 'broken' or 'choppy' curve at their edge. The number of lines is given by n and as n approaches infinity you get the required envelope curve. I want to see how the envelope curve changes if I were to rotate the X axis clockwise by an angle theta.

Comment: @David K or if you are aware of envelopes, i'm trying to find out the envelope of a family of straight lines when the X axis is rotated clockwise by an angle theta

Comment: I assume you rotate *only* the $x$ axis and leave the $y$ axis fixed, is that right? I think that is more interesting than rotating everything the same way.

Comment: Anyway that *is* a very nice problem. (I already said that in a comment but I included a spoiler so I have deleted that earlier comment; did not want to ruin the fun.)

Comment: You're right, I am rotating just the x axis while keeping the y axis fixed. Also, I'd like to mention that for the case where the x and y axes are orthogonal, the substitution $\frac{m}{n} \rightarrow t$ did give me the appropriate envelope curve. However, trying this substitution with the case of a rotation of the x axis I graphed out the parametric function and did not get the correct curve. It is possible I messed up the derivation, though, so I'll do it again.

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I meant to say rotate the y axis and not the x axis. I could use the equation of the envelope of straight lines where the axes are orthogonal(which is $y = \left ( 1-\sqrt{x} \right )^2$) and convert it into parametric form which would be $\begin{pmatrix}x\\ \left ( 1-\sqrt{x} \right )^2\end{pmatrix}$. Then I could apply a linear transformation to that vector where $\hat{i}$ stays constant but $\hat{j}$ gets rotated clockwise by $\theta$ degrees. I guess it would work, but it's not as satisfying as doing the algebra and getting the equation.